# React Native - Is there a way to use bluetooth in peripheral mode?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an app in ReactNative offline.
One of the functionalities is to use bluetooth to synchronize the data (that the app was collecting) with other devices that use the same app.

I started to develop this task with the [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/tree/master/example) library, i can connect from device A to device B, but I don't understand how to listen to the incoming connection in device B. I need to know this to show a certain view.

can anybody help me?
I am using the correct library?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing device A is a smartphone with your app installed. What kind is device B?

Comment: Device A and B use the same app, and can be a Tablet or Smartphone. I must show a certain view when receiving a bluetooth communication on device B from device A. This is to synchronize the forms that were created by both devices. The place where this app is going to be used does not have an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

***Note:* This answer is iOS only since [react-native-peripheral](https://github.com/petrbela/react-native-peripheral) has not implemented Android support yet.**

You can't use only the [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) for this project. The library states in its [readme](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/blob/master/README.md) that it is based on [cordova-plugin-ble-central](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central), which can only act as a central. For a BLE connection you need a central and a peripheral.

Take a look at [react-native-peripheral](https://github.com/petrbela/react-native-peripheral). It allows you to act as a perihperal, create a characteristic with some data, add it to a service and register it so other devices can find it. This is their usage example:

```js
import Peripheral, { Service, Characteristic } from 'react-native-peripheral'

Peripheral.onStateChanged(state => {
  // wait until Bluetooth is ready
  if (state === 'poweredOn') {
    // first, define a characteristic with a value
    const ch = new Characteristic({
      uuid: '...',
      value: '...', // Base64-encoded string
      properties: ['read', 'write'],
      permissions: ['readable', 'writeable'],
    })

    // add the characteristic to a service
    const service = new Service({
      uuid: '...',
      characteristics: [ch],
    })

    // register GATT services that your device provides
    Peripheral.addService(service).then(() => {
      // start advertising to make your device discoverable
      Peripheral.startAdvertising({
        name: 'My BLE device',
        serviceUuids: ['...'],
      })
    })
  }
})
```

There is a section about [dynamic values](https://github.com/petrbela/react-native-peripheral#dynamic-value) where they explain how you can use the `onReadRequest` and  `onWriteRequest` callbacks to listen to read and write operations on the peripheral and even return dynamic values on each read request:

```js
new Characteristic({
  uuid: '...',
  properties: ['read', 'write'],
  permissions: ['readable', 'writeable'],
  onReadRequest: async (offset?: number) => {
    const value = '...' // calculate the value
    return value // you can also return a promise
  },
  onWriteRequest: async (value: string, offset?: number) => {
    // store or do something with the value
    this.value = value
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but react-native-peripheral doesn't have android support. The app must work on both IOS and Android. Any other library to recommend that works on both?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that! I'm not aware of any other library that can do that. I believe your best shot would be to use [native modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro)

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar situation. What do you think if you use this library https://github.com/himelbrand/react-native-ble-peripheral?  It seems to support Android and iOS according to npm notes [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ble-peripheral)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35140107)