# React Native BLE Advertising

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-plx, react-native-ble-manager

I'm trying to create a social app on which you would be able to add a friend by placing your phone next to his/her. I'm trying to make it work on a system working like airdrop (BLE connections). Now here's my problem: I just can't find the right library to send data between two phones, as `react-native-ble-plx` clearly states that it is impossible to send data between two phones... I tried to use `react-native-ble-advertiser`, but the library has been archived a few days ago, and I don't think this library could be used for my project (as the data sent between the two phones would be public).
Is it possible to do so in react native ? Or do I need to use some native components ?
Thanks

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73979832/react-native-is-there-a-way-to-use-bluetooth-in-peripheral-mode